# Is left join and right join sufficient?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let say I have 2 tables like below:

TABLE: PRODUCT

```
-------------
|PRODUCT    |
-------------
|IPAD       |
-------------
|IPHONE     |
-------------
```

TABLE: SALES

```
-----------------------------   
SALES_PERSON|PRODUCT|IS_SOLD|
-----------------------------
ALICE       |IPAD   |   1   |
-----------------------------
JOHN        |IPONE  |   1   |
-----------------------------
```

Is that possible to make SQL statement to produce a result like below?

```
--------------------------------
SALES_PERSON| PRODUCT | IS_SOLD|
--------------------------------
ALICE       | IPAD    | 1      |
--------------------------------
ALICE       | IPHONE  | null   |
--------------------------------
JOHN        | IPAD    | null   |
--------------------------------
JOHN        | IPHONE  | 1      |
--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with joins but you need more than one.  You need to create a cross product between products and sales people.  The left join this to the `sales_person` table:

```
select pe.sales_person, p.product, sp.is_sold
from product p cross join
     (select distinct sales_person from sales) pe left outer join
     sales_person sp
     on sp.product = p.product and
        sp.sales_person = pe.sales_person;
```

Comment: thanks Gordon,
I just found a solution for this too:

select sql1.product, sql1.sales_person, sql2.is_sold
from 
(
 select p.product, s.sales_person, s.is_sold
 from
 product p, sales s
) sql1
left outer join
(
 select p.product, s.sales_person, s.is_sold
 from 
 product p 
 left join sales s on p.product = s.product
) sql2
on (sql1.product = sql2.product);

Comment: @user3418090 . . . Your solution will result in duplicate rows if one `sales_person` appears in more than one row in the `sales_person` table.